# Count of Sequential occurrences and their lengths (advanced gaps and islands problem)

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to find out the count of sequential occurrences and their lengths for a certain user action. Let's say it is monthly logins. Below is a simplified structure of my table and my expected end result.

PostgreSQL Schema Setup:

```
  CREATE TABLE user_actions (
        action_date VARCHAR(255),
        user_id VARCHAR(255)
    );
```

```
INSERT INTO user_actions(action_date, user_id)
VALUES('2020-03', 'alex01'),
('2020-04', 'alex01'),
('2020-05', 'alex01'),
('2020-06', 'alex01'),
('2020-12', 'alex01'),
('2021-01', 'alex01'),
('2021-02', 'alex01'),
('2021-03', 'alex01'),
('2020-04', 'jon03'),
('2020-05', 'jon03'),
('2020-06', 'jon03'),
('2020-09', 'jon03'),
('2021-11', 'jon03'),
('2021-12', 'jon03'),
('2022-01', 'jon03'),
('2022-02', 'jon03'),
('2020-05', 'mark05'),
('2020-06', 'mark05'),
('2020-07', 'mark05'),
('2020-08', 'mark05'),
('2020-09', 'mark05')
```

- alex01 have 2 streak with length of 4
- jon03 have 3 streaks with length of 1, 3 and 4
- mark05 have 1 streak with length of 5
  And we would like to get the occurrence counts of longest streaks per user

| Streak Length | # of occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |

I have tried to research if this type of a problem was asked before and found  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728265/sequential-occurrence-advanced-gaps-and-islands-problem) . Although the answer was quite helpful but not exactly what I need

Comment: Unrelated: PostgreSQL 9.6 is a very old (unsupported) version and lacks tons of features and bug fixes. I suggest you to upgrade your system asap.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo not using that actually sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps to go from your varchar dates to your final output:

- format your dates with `DATE` datatype, to allow for dates comparison
- compute when each date value is not consecutive for each "*user_id*", flag it with 1 and that will represent the beginning of a new partition
- compute a running sum on your flag, to generate your partition values
- retrieve the biggest count of dates within each partition
- count how many counts you have found in the previous step

Each of these steps is made within a subquery:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT user_id, 
           TO_DATE(action_date || '-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_as_date
    FROM user_actions
), islands AS ( 
    SELECT *, 
           CASE WHEN LAG(date_as_date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_as_date) + INTERVAL '1 month' <> date_as_date
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 
           END AS new_partition
    FROM cte
), partitioned_islands AS (
    SELECT user_id, 
           SUM(new_partition) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date_as_date) AS partitions
    FROM islands
), count_per_island AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_consecutive_dates
    FROM partitioned_islands
    GROUP BY user_id, partitions
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
)
SELECT num_consecutive_dates AS streakLength, 
       COUNT(*) AS numOfOccurrences  
FROM count_per_island
GROUP BY streakLength
ORDER BY streakLength DESC
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fYK9WsenpD1xSdT6Nu5EMn/1).

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you very very much. I realized a little flaw with how I structured with my question and the expected result actually. 

Would it be difficult to change the code where it only counts the longest streak per user?
So with the same data set 
Streak Length # of occurrences
5 1
4 2

Comment: Update your post with expected output, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Done! once again greatly appreciated

Comment: Only the "*count_per_island*" subquery was changed to address the updated task, rest is identical. Check the updated fiddle.

Comment: Incredibly done